# What type of data is this: birthweight of newborn baby: 1 = low (<2500g) or 0 = high (>2500g)

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Can anybody tell me what type of data this is, I am not sure what type of categorical data it is as I need to perform the correct statistical test:

Birth weight of newborn babies: low (<2500g) or high (>2500g)

As there are only two categories I am not sure what type it is (ordinal, nominal or binary). Thank you!

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: At first I thought binary because there are only 2 category options but then it is ordered slightly so was thinking ordinal...hence my confusion

Comment: Astute observation, see [Can binary data be ordinal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169604/can-binary-data-be-ordinal).

Comment: do you know the answer?